# Server could not create ASP.pages_assetstore_checkout_aspx

Tags: asp.net, webforms, invalidoperationexception, asp.net-4.8

Strange error I've never seen before:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 17/01/2022 14:56:37 
Event time (UTC): 17/01/2022 14:56:37 
Event ID: 56df87d19084411a8d6b2f2598cecc11 
Event sequence: 40 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-16-132869049850165861 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: REDACTED
    Machine name: DESKTOP-K8J39K7 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 16416 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Server could not create ASP.pages_assetstore_checkout_aspx.
   at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_5hif4s2s.Create_ASP_pages_assetstore_checkout_aspx()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: https://www.constructdev.net:443/pages/assetstore/checkout.aspx?languageID=1 
    Request path: /pages/assetstore/checkout.aspx 
    User host address: REDACTED
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 174 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_5hif4s2s.Create_ASP_pages_assetstore_checkout_aspx()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
 
 
Custom event details:
```

This only appears to affect this single page, and no others on the website.  Apart from making some small code changes nothing material has changed.

Building and cleaning the solution works fine as expected, it's only when I visit the page do I see the error.

Setting compilation `debug=true` doesn't shed any more light.  I've tried deleting the file from the solution, rebuilding then re-adding the file but to no avail - the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, some tool (Resharper?) auto created a constructor for the checkout.aspx.cs Checkout class:

```
    public Checkout(long basketTotalValueCents)
    {
        BasketTotalValueCents = basketTotalValueCents;
    }
```

Not sure where this came from, but deleting it fixed the error.